# VB- Trying To Make A Navigation System Returns Error

Tags: vb.net

Hey so very new to visual basic, trying to create a software similar too the spotify windows application in its looks. I have designed my shell and have a series of buttons for my navigation. I wasn't sure the best way to program them so that different pages could be called, inline with the users button selection. The method iv attempted to use is making User Controls, adding the controls from the toolbox onto my composition and getting them to 'Movetofront' When the corresponding button is clicked.

My Code:

```
Public Sub Nav_Home_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Nav_Home.Click
    Nav_Panel.Top = Nav_Home.Top
    Control_Home.BringToFront()
End Sub
```

Duplicated for each of my navigation buttons, however it returns this error-

```
Reference to a non shared member requires a object reference
```

Iv looked and i cant figure out why it is returning this so would appreciate advice, simple answers pls

Comment: The problem is that something (would have to be either `Nav_Panel` or `Control_Home`) is a *type*, but you are trying to call a member function that requires an *instance* of the type.  In either case, I assume that there is an instance that you should be able to use instead.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe could help you:

Instead of `.BringToFront()` you can set the `TopMost` property to `True` like shown below.

```
Public Sub Nav_Home_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Nav_Home.Click
    Nav_Panel.Top = Nav_Home.Top
    Control_Home.TopMost = True
End Sub
```

This will lock your Control_Home window on the top of everything on the screen.

If you want to turn it off, in order to put another window on the top, just set the property to `False` as shown below:

```
Control_Home.TopMost = False
```

---

***Remarks:***

This will work if you `Control_Home` ***is a Form***. I didn't understand if it's a form or a group of controls. If it's ***not a form tell me*** in the comment, I will update my answer.